# JQuery enable/disable asp:Textboxes based on selected asp:CheckBoxList

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, checkboxlist

I am working on a project where the users will need to enter working hours if a day of the week is selected. The users have requested the fields be disabled until the day is checked.

Ideally I would like to keep it as smart and dynamic as possible, using the day value to build the input, rather than writing separate conditions based on each day.

Here's my basic setup so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO59t.png

And the JQuery to catch the click event, and build the object name:

```
   $("input[type=checkbox][id*=cblDays]").click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    var day = $(this).val();
                    var startControlID = "txtNewStart" + day;
                    var finishControlID = "txtNewFinish" + day;
                    var lunchControlID = "ddlLunchNew" + day;
                    $this.find('input[name$=' + startControlID + ']').attr("disabled", false);

                }
```

I have proven that the "startControlID" variable is being populated with correct ID, but the issue I am having is is the selector doesnt appear to be finding the control.

Does any one have any idea where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution which hopefully will help someone out in the future - I changed the ClientIDMode property to "Static" on the asp:textboxes and modified my jQuery selector to: 
 **$("[id$=" + startControlID + "]").attr("disabled", false);**

So my entire jQuery function is:

$("input[type=checkbox][id*=cblDays]").click(function () {

```
            if (this.checked) {
                var day = $(this).val();
                var startControlID = "txtNewStart" + day;
                var finishControlID = "txtNewFinish" + day;
                var lunchControlID = "ddlLunchNew" + day;
                $("[id$=" + startControlID + "]").attr("disabled", false);
                $("[id$=" + finishControlID + "]").attr("disabled", false);
                $("[id$=" + lunchControlID + "]").attr("disabled", false);
            }
            else {
                var day = $(this).val();
                var startControlID = "txtNewStart" + day;
                var finishControlID = "txtNewFinish" + day;
                var lunchControlID = "ddlLunchNew" + day;
                $("[id$=" + startControlID + "]").attr("disabled", true);
                $("[id$=" + finishControlID + "]").attr("disabled", true);
                $("[id$=" + lunchControlID + "]").attr("disabled", true);
            }
        });
```

Hope this saves someone in future land some time!